# Trigonometry: intersection between two sine curve

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on this optional question on my work, I am not sure how to do it, please teach me.

$5000 \sin(\pi/2(t+0))+6000 = 15000 \sin(\pi/2(t-2.429203673))+25000$

The question is to find t using general solution, which means we need to use the reference angle$(\alpha)$ 
which would something like $\sin(t)= \sin(\alpha), t=n(\pi)+((-1)^(n))(\alpha),$ then we sub n with numbers to find t.

The question ask me to do it algebraically, if the word algebraically is not there, I could do it with the graphics calculator, and I know how to do it. But It does say algebraically so, I don't know how.

Comment: You could start by dividing everything by 1000... even then those numbers don't give a friendly look.  And why the $t+0$ instead of $t$?

Comment: I do not know where $2.429203673$ is coming from but it really looks like $4-\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: 2.429203673 is from -time to maximum + 1/4 period(which is 4). The time to maximum is given(pi/2 - 1) before the research start, and on the graph, the time to maximum after the research start is 3.something, so I did 3+(1-(pi/2 - 1)). The other number would work the same is t + pi /2 instead of t - 2.429... (-[-(pi/2 - 1)] + 1/4(4) = pi/2)

Comment: I wrote t+0 just because that's how the equation form without any work. It could be just t i guess

Answer (score 1):

We can start by writing the equation in a simpler form:

$$5\sin nt+6=15\sin(nt-n\alpha)+25$$

Expanding using the compound angle formula, we get:

$$\sin nt(5+15\cos n\alpha)+15\cos nt\sin n\alpha=19$$

We can now do a compound angle transformation, writing the LHS in the form $$R\sin(nt+\theta)$$

We then end up with having to solve numerically

$$\sin(nt+\theta)=\frac{19}{\sqrt{250+150\cos n\alpha}},$$

where$$\tan\theta=\frac{3\sin n\alpha}{1+3\cos n\alpha}$$ and $n=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha=2.429203673$

Answer (score 1):

With $\theta:=\pi t/2$, the equation can be written

$$a\sin(\theta)+b=c\sin(\theta+\phi)+d,$$ or using the addition formula and reworking,

$$(c\cos(\phi)-a)\sin(\theta)+c\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)=d.$$

This trigonometric equation is of the form

$$A\sin(\theta)+B\cos(\theta)=C$$ and we can rationalize it with the relations

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{2u}{1+u^2},\\\cos(\theta)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2},$$ giving

$$2Au+B(1-u^2)=C(1+u^2).$$

You should be able to solve this quadratic equation in $u$. Then

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{2u}{1-u^2}=\frac{2\tan(\theta/2)}{1-\tan^2(\theta/2)},$$ so that

$$\theta=2\arctan(u).$$